Handling HttpContext.Session between .NET 8 and .NET Standard 2.0
Let’s say, there is a class in .NET standard 2.0 project where class contains a method parameter of HttpContext. This class will be referenced in .NET 8 project.
Both projects use Microsoft.Aspnetcore.SystemWebAdapters NuGet.
In .NET 8, HttpContext is used with the help of IHttpContextAccessor and context.Session will be of type ISession.
I shall add few keys to this context’s Session.
Now, I have to call class method from .NET standard 2.0. When context object is passed in .NET standard, context.Session is null cause it refers System.Web namespace hence, session property is null.
Could somebody explain with small POC to handle session in such scenario?
Thanks in advance.
I tried creating httpcontextwrapper class in .NET 8 inheriting System.Web so that wrapper class is used to convert context to System.Web
This approach didn’t work.

the SDK version is what it is... .net standard 2.0 is just a target. I believe core code will always run in core run-time.  So we know you have a .NET8 project, but the other project is ???  (pretty much any version can target .net standard 2.0)

In .net framework session were managed using System.Web. In ASP.NET Core, these are under Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http with different handling. and because of this difference when passing HttpContext from .NET 8 to a .NET 2.0 library, sessions appear null.to achieve your requirement you could try to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters to create an adapter that translates the modern HttpContext to mimic System.Web, allowing the library to access session data .

In .net framework session were managed using System.Web. In ASP.NET Core, these are under Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http with different handling. and because of this difference when passing HttpContext from .NET 8 to a .NET 2.0 library, sessions appear null.to achieve your requirement you could try to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters to create an adapter that translates the modern HttpContext to mimic System.Web, allowing the library to access session data .
Below is sample code:
Program.cs:
using LegacyLibrary;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Web;
using WebApplication5;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Add memory cache for session storage
builder.Services.AddSession(); // Add session services

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession(); // Session must be enabled before accessing it

app.UseAuthorization();

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Session.SetString("MyKey", "MyValue");

    // Test reading the value back
    var testValue = context.Session.GetString("MyKey");
    Console.WriteLine($"Session value for 'MyKey': {testValue}");

    await next();
});


app.MapGet("/", async (IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) =>
{
    var legacyHandler = new LegacyHandler();

    // Adapt the current HttpContext to System.Web.HttpContextBase
    var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    var adaptedContext = new CustomHttpContextAdapter(httpContext!);

    // Pass the adapted context to the legacy handler
    legacyHandler.ProcessRequest(adaptedContext);

    await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Processed successfully.");
});


app.Run();

CustomHttpContextAdapter.cs:
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication5
{
    public class CustomHttpContextAdapter : HttpContextBase
    {
        private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext _coreContext;

        public CustomHttpContextAdapter(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext coreContext)
        {
            _coreContext = coreContext;
        }

        public override HttpSessionStateBase Session
        {
            get
            {
                // You need to create a custom HttpSessionStateBase that wraps ASP.NET Core's ISession.
                return new CustomSessionStateAdapter(_coreContext.Session);
            }
        }

        // Implement other members of HttpContextBase if needed
    }

    public class CustomSessionStateAdapter : HttpSessionStateBase
    {
        private readonly ISession _session;

        public CustomSessionStateAdapter(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public override object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                return _session.GetString(name);
            }
            set
            {
                _session.SetString(name, value.ToString());
            }
        }

        // You can implement other members as needed
    }

}

LegacyHandler.cs:
using System;
using System.Web;

namespace LegacyLibrary
{
    public class LegacyHandler
    {
      
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase context)
        {
            if (context.Session != null)
            {
                string value = context.Session["MyKey"] as string;
            
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Session is null.");
            }
        }
    }

}

Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SystemWebAdapters nuget package

